# File existence after AFNetworking download

Tags: afnetworking, nsfilemanager

I'm having some issues with finding my file after downloading it with AFNetworking...
The download itself goes fine, but when I check for the existence of the file afterwards, I can't find it... So I'm hoping someone can help me out...

In my code, I download the file, and in the completion block, I check for the existence (this is only done since I'm having issues finding it, it will be removed afterwards)...

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file removed"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename removed"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"filename removed" append:NO];

//Track the progress
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
{
    if (totalBytesExpectedToRead > 0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *progress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloaded %lld of %lld bytes",
                               totalBytesRead,
                               totalBytesExpectedToRead];

            NSLog(@"%@", progress);
        });
    }
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to %@", path);

    //Check for existence
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSLog(@"File found");
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"File not found");
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Any ideas where it might be going wrong? As the download itself goes fine, the problem must lie with saving the file / the file system in iOS...

Answer (score 5):

Does the directory you're trying to write to exist? If not you may find `[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"filename removed" append:NO]` is returning `nil`.

Try creating the directory first:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *folder = [@"filename removed" stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:folder]) {
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:folder
  withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                   attributes:nil
                        error:nil];
}
```

I hope that helps.